# Is $p\in\big\{x,...,2x\big\}$ lower-bounding $p\in\big\{x^2,...,(x+1)^2\big\}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it overreaching or erroneous to consider that possibility? (Alas, I'm not a mathematician, and don't have rigorous language to talk about this.)

What I want to say is: *Given any even span of integers, the number of primes greater than half the span is nearly equivalent to the prime count between the square numbers for which this is an interval.*

Here's a graph that plots the relationship, with the prime count per interval as a constant value (of 1).

[image]

For the first 20,000 perfect square intervals, the average value of the  $p\in\big\{x,...,2x\big\}$ is 0.952 of  $p\in\big\{x^2,...,(x+1)^2\big\}$. It's under the true prime count for 97.6% of intervals, is the same for 0.4%, and is above for 2.0%.

I have the [graphed data here](http://www.naturalnumbers.org/20000.csv) and a [small program to generate data](http://www.naturalnumbers.org/IntervGen.zip).)

Answer (score 1):

The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), in the form
$$
\#\{p\le x\} \sim \frac x{\log x} + \frac x{(\log x)^2}
$$
(here $\log$ is the natural logarithm), implies that the number of primes between $x$ and $2x$ is asymptotic to
$$
\frac x{\log x} - (2\log2-1) \frac x{(\log x)^2}
$$
when $x$ is large. It also implies that *on average*, the number of primes between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ is asymptotic to
$$
\frac x{\log x} + \tfrac12 \frac x{(\log x)^2}.
$$
Unfortunately, we are currently unable to prove this latter statement for *all* large $x$. If we could, then it would imply that for all large $x$, there would be more primes between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ than between $x$ and $2x$, although the limit (number of primes between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$)/(number of primes between $x$ and $2x$) would tend to $1$.

Comment: Could you spell out for me what a limit of 1 would mean if there were a proof?

Comment: @michaelmross A limit of $1$ means that as go look further to the right, your graph would be confined to a narrower and narrower strip around the red line.  This is one precise way (but not the only way) to interpret the phrase "nearly equivalent" in your highlighted speculation.